# django rest framework filter on related tables

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i need help filtering on a field on a related table.

I have tow models Kalas and names, where one (Kalas model) has a one to one relation with the basic User model:

```
class Kalas(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    visitKalas = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    isActive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    capacity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="default name")
    phoneNumber = models.IntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    postal = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    lat = models.FloatField(default=0)
    lng = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return "user: %s, address: %s %s" % (self.user, self.address, self.postal)

class names(models.Model):
    kalasID = models.ForeignKey(Kalas, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='names')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and i have made a nested serializer:

```
class NamesMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = names
    fields = ['name']


class KalasMapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): #bruk denne hver gang man vil ha kalas og navn sammen
    names = NamesMapSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Kalas
        fields = ['id', 'fullName', 'capacity', 'lat', 'lng', 'names']


class MapSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    kalas = KalasMapSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'kalas']
```

and a view that lists all users and its kalas with names:

```
class MapViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    permissions_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    serializer_class = MapSerializer
```

but i dont know how to filter so it only shows users with kalas that i active kalas.isActive=True.

i've tried this, but now its checking the User models is_active and not Kalas's isActive field:

```
class ActiveOnMap(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.all().filter(isActive=True)
    serializer_class = MapSerializer
```

pls help im a newbie:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your query set filter like below:

```
class ActiveOnMap(generics.ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(kalas__isActive=True)
    serializer_class = MapSerializer
```

I hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!! :) I have upvoted your answer but since i dont have more than 15 in reputations it won't show. THANK U!